# Mysql date error creating a table

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an error when I try to create an sql table which I can't fix:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__websitemanager_magazine` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`asset_id` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'FK to the #__assets table.',
`date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`magazine_file` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
```

) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

it throws an Invalid default value for 'date'.  I'm using mysql 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error due to using an empty string as a default value for a `date` data type. The other answers are off in the solution, as using functions such as `NOW` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is not supported for the `date` data type in MySQL. These functions do not provide constant values.

[Create Table Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

> The default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column

When declaring a `date` as `NOT NULL`, [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) allows the usage of the zero value `0000-00-00` in place of null values. To fix your SQL statement, you need to change `DEFAULT '0000-00-00'`.

> MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values, and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE mode.

You can also leave the `DEFAULT` as a whole, as the [Data Type Defaults](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) documentation states `0000-00-00` is an implicit default for dates

> For date and time types other than TIMESTAMP, the default is the appropriate “zero” value for the type

Answer (score 1):

You do not need quotes around your field strings. You also have an empty string at the end of your date line which you do not need, which could be throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put an empty string for default value of date.  Try something like:

```
`date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__websitemanager_magazine` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `asset_id` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'FK to the #__assets table.',
    `date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     `magazine_file` TEXT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Every time when you are putting any date value either make it NULL and put default NULL or if you don't want to create it nullable value make it NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.